# Using front matter title as for url permalink

Tags: jekyll, yaml-front-matter

How can I use my front matter for the url instead of the file name?

I have a collection set up in my `_config.yml`

```
collections:
      news:
        output: true
```

I want to be able to use the `page.title` as my url, below is my front matter

```
---
layout: newspost
title:  "Fracture announces exclusive 3 year deal with Drake & Morgan."
date:   2019-01-16
---
```

currently the url is the file name of the `.md` file as so:

`http://localhost:4000/news/drake_and_morgan.html`

I would like the output for the url to be as follows:

`http://localhost:4000/news/Fracture-announces-exclusive-3-year-deal with-Drake-&-Morgan.` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `slug` in front matter :

```
---
layout: newspost
title:  "Fracture announces exclusive 3 year deal with Drake & Morgan."
date:   2019-01-16
slug: "fracture-announces-exclusive-3-year-deal-with-drake-and-morgan"
---
```

And define a default `permalink` for news :

```
collections:
  news:
    output: true
    permalink: "/:collection/:slug/"
```

OR

You can work a little more on filenames and end-up with a **fracture-announces-exclusive-3-year-deal-with-drake-and-morgan.md** filename. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, David this worked, never really figured out how slugs work. Thank you for explaining that. But you're right I could just change the filename. lol I guess i have learnt how to use slugs though i guess i was really hoping to use the title, and jekyll some how replace spaces with - ha

Answer (score 0):

_config.yml

```
collections:
  news:
    output: true
    permalink: /news/:title
```